# Android ImageView scaleType

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an image to be used a background in activity:

[image]

I want this image to fit screen by its height.
It means that for wide-screen smartphones, I want my image to be fit by height and centered:

[image]

and for square-screen smartphones, I want my image to be cut:

[image]

I use `ImageView` for the image. What `scaleType` should I use? Looking at the second figure, I'd say to use `android:scaleType="centerInside"`. But looking at the third, I'd say to use `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`. What is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your evaluation of the different `scaleType`'s is correct. If you want the whole image to be visible, use `"centerInside"`, or if you want to fill the whole view then use `centerCrop`.

To use a mix of both, you can set the `scaleType` in your `onCreate()` method. Based on the behavior you want to have, you can check the orientation or size of the screen and set the appropriate choice.

`imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE); // or ScaleType.CENTER_CROP`

Answer (score 1):

You can have two layouts, one for each of your configurations. You can then load the proper one at the activity's onCreate() call.

Answer (score 1):

When you fit one side of image to background, you will face with two problems, first one is screen width is bigger than image's width or screen height is bigger than image height.So you will have empty space.

If you do not want to face with resolution problem and you want to fit both side of image to background, you need to use `centerCROP`.But as i said, if one side of image is not enough to fit background, image gets bigger till it will be filled.

Answer (score 0):

Use `centerCrop` because `centerInside` doesn't scale an image in a view and you have to create the image with appropriate height to achieve wide-screened smartphones background filling. Or alternative you could use `fitCenter` to get uniformly scaled image by both axes which fills the all background.

Comment: This actually isn't correct. `centerInside` will scale to fit the image but not exceed the view's dimensions. `center` does not scale and just centers the image in the view. image. You can read the full description of the different types here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: You are right but the task was not about showing a background image virgin and undistorted.